# How to share twbx file so that other party doesn't have to have the excel files and can refresh the data?

Tags: excel, extract, tableau-api

So my twbx has two data sources. One of them is a database connection (Customer SQL Query) joined with an excel file using data connection. The other data source is an excel file.

When I try to refresh the data on tableau desktop and the file path for the excel files have changed, it asks me to specify the file path. I thought when you create an extract of a twb file a copy of data is stored in the tableau file. This is strange because another twbx file I created which also uses an excel file joined with database doesn't ask me for a file path every time I refresh the extracts.

When the refresh happens, what I am really trying to do is just refresh the database connection, and its okay if the excel files stay the same. I saw this 
post (http://drawingwithnumbers.artisart.org/o-extract-where-art-thou/)  and applied its methods but they were of no use.

I have tried to find differences between the two, and except for the fact that one uses an additional data source (not data connection) in form of an excel file, nothing really is different.

Just to be more specific, this is not something in Tableau Server/Online, this is all happening in tableau desktop

Comment: Have you created extracts of all the data sources before saving the .twbx before sending? Even then, of course, you will still need to know where the original excel file is to *refresh* the extract.

Comment: Try using a twb file instead of twbx - and just avoid the issue of what is copied to a twbx - assuming all parties have Tableau Desktop instead of Tableau Reader

Comment: @matt_black ,yes I created extracts before saving the .twbx. And I would think that maybe knowing the filepath is necessary, but I have another twbx which doesn't ask for any filepath during refresh and can work on anyone's device with tableau in it. Which is what I am wondering, if it can be done in one, then it can be done in another

Comment: @AlexBlakemore if I use a twb file, then everytime I share the file via email, I have to send them the excel files as well, since as soon as you open the twb file, it will ask for those data sources for the file to work

Comment: @AmitSinghParihar I've seen similar behaviour on refresh but only if I'm trying to refresh the file on a computer where the sources are stored in a different place. Tableau .twbx remembers the path to the data so won't ask for it on refresh if the data turns up in the expected place.